# Access listView model inside another model

Tags: javascript, listview, qml

I've the following scenario:

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel
}

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: myModel
    delegate: recipeDelegate
}    

Component {
    id: recipeDelegate

    Item {
        ...
        ...

        property var modelTag: row.model

        ListView
        {
            id: row
            delegate: recipeDelegateTags                   
            width: parent.width
            height: contentItem.height

            model: ListModel {
                id: myModel2
               }
         }
 }

Component { // I need to access this 

    id: recipeDelegateTags

    Item {
        id: recipeTags 
        width: parent.width
        height: 35

        Text {
            id: ic
            font.family: fontAwesome.name
            color: cor
            font.pixelSize: 16
            text: checked_ ? "\uf046" : "\uf096"
            width: 15

            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 50
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }

        MediumText
        {
            anchors.verticalCenter: ic.verticalCenter
            text: titulo
            color: cor
            font.family: localFont.name
            anchors.left: ic.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to append data in myModel with a js function like this:

```
function appendItem(a, b)
{
    myModel.append({"titulo": a, "id": b})
}
```

**The question: how I access myModel2 to append some data?**

I've already tried the following, without success:

```
function adicionaTag(a, b, c, d)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < myModel.count; i++) {
      var elemCur = myModel.get(i);
      if(a === elemCur.id) {
         console.log("property", elemCur.modelTag);
      }
   }
}
```

Can you guys help me? Thanks!

Comment: You wan't to access `myModel2`? Have you tried `myModel2.append()`?

Comment: @derM yes I did. In fact, I have tried: 

elemCur.modelTag.append(b, c, d)
elemCur.myModel2.append(b, c, d)

and received this error: **TypeError: Cannot call method 'append' of undefined**

I must use properties to access items inside the parent model, right?

Comment: You can't access the model before it is instantiated. If you want to access an object by `id`, said `id` needs to be in scope. So - if you have an `id` within a component, and instantiat this component multiple times, the `id` would not be an identifier anymore, if all of them would be in the same scope. So the `id`s of objects within an `Component` are hidden to the objects outside this `Component` just as they would be, when you had the `Component` declared in some other file.

Comment: If you would call `model2.append()` from within the `Component` with the `id: recipeDelegate` it would be no problem, but as soon as you try it from the outside, there would be no guarantee that the `id` is unique. What is it, you wan't to append to the model and when do you want to do this?

Comment: @derM thank your for the explanation. I was trying to make a loop inside a jsonarray, identifying the id and appending to my second model, but in the end was easier just pass a string comma separated and then use myModel.append().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION:**

The resolution was based on @Maciek comment and @derM explanation. As I was using QJsonArray, I thought I could just loop and then access the myModel2 child component. Well, it's not that easy like that, as explained in the comments, the component can not be easily accessed. I have tried in many ways, both by loop in QML and in c ++ using findChild <>. In the end, it was much easier to just loop in QJSonArray and put it all together in a string, pass as an argument in myModel.append and then use the js split function:

```
Component {
   id: recipeDelegate

   Item {
    ...
    ...

       TagComponnent
       {
        id: row
        myString: someData               
      }
    }
 }
```

Inside TagComponent:

```
Item {    
    property string myString
    property variant stringList

     onMyStringChanged:
     {
        stringList = myString.split(';')
        var arrayLength = stringList.length

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
           appendItem(stringList[i], stringList[i+1])
           i++
    }
     }


     function adicionaTag(a, b)
     {
        myModel.append({"titulo": a, "cor": b})
     }        

     ListModel {
       id: myModel
     }

    ListView {
       ...
       model: myModel
       delegate: recipeDelegateTags
  }

 Component {
    id: recipeDelegateTags

       Item {
           ...
           ...

           MediumText
          {
              text: titulo
              color: cor
          }
      }
  }
}
```

To append:

```
function appendItem(a)
{
  myModel.append("myString": someData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your example and I have few conclusions:

```
function adicionaTag(a, b, c, d)
{    
    for(var i = 0; i< myModel.count; i++) 
    {
      var elemCur = myModel.get(i);
      if(a === elemCur.id) 
      {
         console.log("property", elemCur) 
      }
    }
}
```

.

```
Component 
{
    id: recipeDelegate

    Item 
    {

        property var modelTag: row.model
        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            console.log("Item onCompleted, ", this)
        }

        ListView
        {

            id: row
            delegate: recipeDelegateTags
            width: parent.width
            height: contentItem.height

            model: ListModel {
                id: myModel2
               }
         }
    }
}
```

Objects in the two outputs are not the same. Component.onCompleted prints QQuickItem but our adicionaTag function gives QObject. So i think that object returned by get function contains only properties given by append, or setProperty methods, maybe something like "attached properties".

**You have two options now**

One is to use the listview's itemAt method to get the reference and then append your data.

The second one is to work on properties given to your model's methods, ie. You can append myModel2 from data that you pass.

```
function appendItem(a, b)
{
   myModel.append({"titulo": a, "id": b, "someData" : 55})
}
```

and then:

```
Component 
{
   id: recipeDelegate

   Item 
   {
        property var modelTag: row.model
        Component.onCompleted:
        {
         console.log("Item onCompleted, ", this)
         row.model.append({"anotherData" : someData})
        }
        ListView
        {
          id: row
          delegate: recipeDelegateTags
          width: parent.width
          height: contentItem.height

          model: ListModel {
             id: myModel2
          }
        }
    }
}
```

now you can acces to "someData" from recipeDelegateTags:

```
Item {
    id: recipeTags
    width: parent.width
    height: 35
    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        console.log("child component: anotherData: ", anotherData)
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
There is also another, third way:

```
function adicionaTag(a, b, c, d)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < listView.children.length; i++) {
      var elemCur =listView.children[i];
      console.log("property", elemCur);
   }
}
```

Comment: the option 2 solved my problem. I'll update the question with your solution. Thank you!